# Using "override" or just plain redefine the subroutine in perl

Tags: perl

Have this example code - 2 packages which extends the `Some` package and redefines the `func` method.

```
use 5.014;
use warnings;

package Some {
    use Moose;
    use warnings;
    sub func { say 'func from Some'; }
}

package Over {
    use Moose;
    use warnings;
    extends 'Some';
    override 'func' => sub { say 'func from Over'; };
}

package Plain {
    use Moose;
    use warnings;
    extends 'Some';
    sub func { say 'func from Plain'; };
}

#main
for my $package ( qw(Some Over Plain) ) {
    my $instance = $package->new();
    $instance->func;
}
```

runnig the code gives:

```
func from Some
func from Over
func from Plain
```

e.g. the `func` method is redefined in both cases, without any warning or such.

The questions:

- are here some meaningful differences between the two ways?
- when I should use the `override` and when the *plain* redefine?
- is this discussed in some doc?

Comment: No methods are redefined. You are defining three different methods `Some::func`, `Over::func`, and `Plain::func`.

Comment: @mob hm.. and what the te correct terminology? assuming, that for the `Over` is  `override` instead of the redefine, but how to call the `Plain` scenario if the _redefine_ isn't correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [documentation](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Moose) answers this perfectly.

> `override ($name, &sub)`
>
> An override method is a way of explicitly saying "I am overriding this method from my superclass". You can call `super` within this method, and it will work as expected. The same thing can be accomplished with a normal method call and the `SUPER::` pseudo-package; it is really your choice.

Comment: There's a difference mentioned. One provides `super`; the other doesn't.

Comment: Also override will throw an exception if the base class doesn't define the method you're overriding.